# How can I recursively print the elements of a list twice?

Tags: recursion, lisp

I need to write a recursive function that prints out the elements of a list twice.  For example, rdouble '(1 2 3) would print (1 1 2 2 3 3) and rdouble'(1 (2  3) 4) would print (1 1 (2 2 3 3) 4 4).

So far I have:

```
(defun rdouble(struct)
 (cond
     ((atom struct) struct)
     (t (cons (rdouble (car struct)) (cons (car struct) 
              (rdouble (cdr struct))
        )))))
```

This works fine for the first example but prints

```
(1 1 (2 2 3 3) (2 3) 4 4)
```

for the second example. How do I continue to print out each element twice but not reprint (2 3)? What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: When you say, "print", do you mean "return"? And if this is homework, you should add the "homework" tag.

Comment: Yes, I mean return... sorry about the tag, its my first time on the forum...

Comment: does it have to be recursive? this is much easier to do with `loop` :P

Comment: @Gareth: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @Vinay, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 4):

The expression has THREE different cases:

1. an atom -> return it
2. a cons with an atom as the CAR -> double it
3. a cons with a cons as the CAR -> walk down

Your code handles only two cases, where your second case mixes 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

the reason it is causing the problems you are experiencing is that given `((1 2) 3)` your code recurses into `(1 2)`, which correctly becomes `(1 1 2 2)` *and* then adds `(1 2)` (being the `car` in the first call) after the `(1 1 2 2)` giving `((1 1 2 2) (1 2) ...)`

what would be best is to make `rdouble` *always* return a list, and `append` those lists together instead of `cons`ing them